# Mark list of students finding average

Tags: c#, arrays

Here when I sum the average of four subjects of student1 separately and like that when I proceed with student2 his average is being added with student1. Why is a separate average for each student not calculated? Please help.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 namespace ConsoleApplication3
 {
     class stud
     {
         static void Main (string[] args)
         {
             double[,] studentavg = new double[3, 4];
             double total = 0;
             int ch = 0;
             int i, j;

             while (ch == 0)
             {
                 for (i = 0; i < studentavg.GetLength(0); i++)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Enter mark of student : {0}", i + 1);

                     for (j = 0; j < studentavg.GetLength(1); j++)
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Enter mark : {0}", j + 1);
                         studentavg[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                         total += studentavg[i, j];
                     }
                     Console.WriteLine("Average is: {0}", (total / studentavg.GetLength(1)));
                     Console.Write("Enter 1 for exit OR 0 for continue: ");
                     ch = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                 }
             }
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sure someone will point out of the problem in a few minutes. In the meantime just use your debugger and step through the code line-by-line and keep an eye on the value of the `total` variable.

Comment: Thank you Dirk and Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the line
"double total = 0;"
outside the while loop.
Don't you need to initialize it each time to zero?

You should also avoid 
"Convert.ToInt16"
and replace it by
"if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ch)) { error, re-enter number } else all ok"
Try to avoid predefined integer sizes. And a conversion from string to a number can always fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are never resetting `total` back to 0 between students. Try adding

```
total = 0
```

after

```
ch = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: No problems @user3410213